# Paste image into latex quickly?

Tags: diagrams, includegraphics, vscode

Every time when I write some short thing with latex, and have some pictures to insert, I have to save the picture with a specified name in a specified directory first and then type the `include...` to insert the picture(I know snippet can make it quicker but still not what I want), which will become especially inconvenient when using screenshot.

So I want to know is there some method to realize the function that paste an image from the clipboard just like how Word do it(VSCode method will be better)? The image can be kept in a default directory and with default name.

Comment: No. The way with `includegraphics`and on it derived commands are only one options. LaTeX is not Word.

Comment: LaTeX knows nothing about file editing, it would be possible for your editor to support  image paste by saving the data to a file and writing the `\includegraphics` with the generated filename, but (if vscode can do that) is more a question for a vscode forum than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use extension for VSCode: `Paste Image`, then it will save pictures by shortcuts `ctrl+alt+v` into default folder and give name to the picture by default. As for latex code, just create a snippet for figure is enough.